# Where should i put async and await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Where should i put async and await?
result is
work2
work1

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    const txtupload = multer().any()
    let validate = true
    txtupload(req,res, (err)=>{
        console.log('work1')
        validate = false
    })

    if(validate){
        console.log('work2')
        //code
    }
});
```

Comment: In this case you probably don’t use `async`/`await` at all and just put all your code into the inner callback.

Comment: Before uploading i want to put some condition to prevent upload. after txt upload i will put upload again for files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it's an arrow function, you have to put it before the **parameters**:

```
app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => { ... }
```

Comment: I don't know if that's called "variables" there but I wanna know if it's something else, really.

Comment: They're called "parameters; " the whole thing is called a "parameter list." But the OP's code can't use `await`, so this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Oh yeah, but he might be looking at it because of something else. And, since **multer** is a middleware I think he should use it before the _parameters_: `app.post('/upload', multer().any(), (req, res) => { ... }`

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#error-handling), that's one of two ways of using it (the other is roughly the way the OP is using it).

Comment: FYI, there's no use for an `async` function here because there's no promises being used and thus there's no place to put `await`.  This answer probably misleads the OP into thinking they can use `await` with `txtupload()` which they can't unless they promisify it first.

Answer (score 3):

The upload function from `multer` doesn't return a promise, so `async`/`await` isn't applicable. Instead, issue your response in the callback.

Your real question seems to be: How do I use `multer` to handle file uploads? For that we go to the [`multer` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#any). Adapting that documentation to your code:

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    const txtupload = multer().any();
    txtupload(req,res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            // ...it failed, send a failure response via `res`...
        } else {
            // ...it worked, send a success response via `res`...
        }
    });
    // Don't do anything here, the upload hasn't been processed yet
});
```

But refer to the examples in the documentation, there are other patterns for using `multer`.